# How to do tail call optimisation in Scala3?

Tags: scala, recursion, callstack, stack-frame, tail-call-optimization

I am trying to write a program that is 100% iterative, that is, the functions never need to return, because nothing must happen after such a return.

In other words, the program is 100% in tail position.
Consider the following toy program:

```
  def foo(): Unit =
    bar()

  def bar(): Unit =
    foo()

  try
    foo()
  catch
    case s: StackOverflowError =>
      println(" Stack overflow!")
```

call foo indeed results in a stack overflow which is no surprise, indeed foo calls bar, as such bar needs a stack frame, bar then calls foo, which gain needs a stack frame, etc. It is clear why the stack overflow error occurs.

My question is, how can I define foo and bar as they are, without having a stack overflow? Languages like Scheme allow this program, they would run forever, yes, but the stack would not grow because it knows that nothing needs to happen after calling, e.g., bar from foo, so there is no need to keep the stack frame for foo upon the call to bar. Clearly scala (i.e., the JVM?) does keep the stack frame alive.

Now consider the next code example:

```
  def foo(): Unit = 
    foo()

  foo()
```

This program will run forever, but there will never occur a stack overflow.

I am aware of the @tailrec annotation, but to my understanding it would only be applicable to a situation like the second example, but not for the first example.

Any ideas?
(I need the first example to run forever like the second example, without having stack overflow.)

Comment: Optimising mutually recursive calls requires tail call elimination rather than simple tail recursion. This is not supported by the JVM because it does not support non-local jumps, so you need to use iteration or trampolining.

Comment: You *can* implement proper tail calls on the JVM. Scala just chooses not to, because you can't make it both fast and interoperable.

Comment: the Scala standard library has a utility class that provides trampolining: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/util/control/TailCalls$.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you note, the JVM forbids non-local jumps, thus if `foo` and `bar` are compiled as separate methods (which is generally desirable), tail call elimination is impossible.

However, you can trampoline, by having your `foo` and `bar` return a value which the caller interprets as "call this function".

```scala
sealed trait TrampolineInstruction[A]

case class JumpOff[A](value: A) extends TrampolineInstruction[A]
case class JumpAgain[A](thunk: => TrampolineInstruction[A])
  extends TrampolineInstruction[A]

@tailrec
def runTrampolined(ti: TrampolineInstruction[A]): A =
  ti match {
    case JumpOff(value) => value
    case JumpAgain(thunk) => runTrampolined(thunk)
  }

def foo(): TrampolineInstruction[Unit] = JumpAgain(bar())
def bar(): TrampolineInstruction[Unit] = JumpAgain(foo())

runTrampolined(foo())  // will not overflow the stack, never completes
```

[Cats provides an `Eval` monad](http://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/eval.html) which encapsulates the idea of trampolining.  The above definitions of `foo` and `bar` are then

```scala
import cats.Eval

def foo(): Eval[Unit] = Eval.defer(bar())
def bar(): Eval[Unit] = Eval.defer(foo())

foo().value  // consumes a bounded (very small, not necessarily 1) number of stack frames, never completes
```

The monadic qualities of `Eval` may prove useful for expressing more complex logic without the risk of calling `value` in the middle of the chain.

Note: `JumpOff` in the first snippet is basically `Eval.Leaf` (generally constructed using `Eval.now`) and `JumpAgain` is basically `Eval.Defer`.

Comment: Using Scala2 syntax, but it should still be valid Scala3

Comment: Thank you, do I understand it correct that both code examples u provided are conceptually the same? I tried running the second snippet, though it stops after two calls (I added println("foo") and for bar in both functions), when I add a '.value' to the foo and bar invocations within the functions bodies, I again get a stack overflow.

Comment: `Eval.defer` in place of `Eval.always` actually looks like a better fit

Comment: you don't have to write your own trampoline or use Cats; you can use https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/util/control/TailCalls$.html